# Can anyone connect tp my node js server with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, socket.io, client

I started working with node.js and socket.io few days ago and I have a question about security.

Let´s say I have a public server (without SSL) and I run there a node.js server side app which listens on port, for example 3000.

I also created a client side - desktop app which is connected to the server.

And my question is: Can anyone who knows ip and port where i am running the server side app connect to it with their own programmed client?

Comment: Next time consider [security.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, if the server is publicly available and the client has the specified port open, yes. They would need to know your event interface for handling the actual communication though. Also this assumes that you have no authentication middleware preventing anyone from connecting.

Comment: That helps. Thanks. Is there any easy way to perform the authentication? My idea is to create some unique string on client side and also on server side. Then on connection event compare that strings and if they are equal let the client connect, othervise not. But I don´t know too much about receiving data on connection event. :/

Comment: You would need to use socket middleware, it works very similarly to how connect (express) middleware works. You can read more about it [in the socket.io docs](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-use-fn). You'd just put your authentication function as the middleware callback.